# Pybind11 binding to access Gst.Buffer

Tags: python, c++, gstreamer, pybind11

I am trying to create a pybind wrapper which acts upon the python-Gst.Buffer. I believe hashing the Gst.buffer gives out the address of its C struct. How do I make the C++ code work with it? Following snippet is what I want to achieve:

**Wrapper Code**

```
void operate_on_buffer(GstBuffer* buf_addr){
    printf("Got Buffer");
    /*...operations on buffer...*/
}

// What needs to be changed here for it to accept hash(buffer)?
PYBIND11_MODULE(mywrapper, m) {
m.def("operate_on_buffer", &operate_on_buffer);
}
```

**Python Code**

```
def do_transform(self, buffer):
    mywrapper.operate_on_buffer(hash(buffer))
```

Comment: guess that depends on what `hash` returns and whether pybind11 can handle that.

Comment: this [page](https://github.com/jackersson/gstreamer-python) has some info on how to convert a gst buffer to a `ndarray`. such an array can be passed to pybind11 as a`py::buffer` or a `py::array`, see [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html#arrays)